# Using SharePoint 2013 Cross-Domain Library in a simple web page: is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page hosted on a server, say at `http://SVR1/path/index.html`, and I would like to access some list items in a on-premises SharePoint site hosted on another server, say at `http://SVR2/sites/mySite/`.

The current installation of SharePoint I am using (not under my control) does not allow deployment of neither SharePoint-hosted nor Provider-hosted apps, so I am trying to use the SharePoint Cross-Domain library to access the desired list items from a purely external HTML5/JS/CSS3 page. I, as a user, have full access rights to the list in my SharePoint site, so I guess it should be no problem reading its items.

Following an example found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927%28v=office.15%29.aspx), my page is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Application Template</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var hostweburl = "http://SVR2/sites/mySite";
    var appweburl  = "http://SVR1/path";

    // Load the required SharePoint libraries
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#renderList").html("Requesting Lists...");

      // resources are in URLs in the form:
      // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
      var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15";

      // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
      $.getScript(scriptbase + "/SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
    });

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Function to prepare and issue the request to get
    //  SharePoint data
    function execCrossDomainRequest() {
      // executor: The RequestExecutor object
      // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
      var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

      // Issue the call against the host web.
      // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
      //      hostweburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
      // The response formats the data in the JSON format.
      // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
      //      sucess and error events respectively.
      executor.executeAsync(
          {
            url: hostweburl + "/_api/web/lists",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
          }
      );
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Function to handle the success event.
    // Prints the data to the page.
    function successHandler(data) {
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
      var listsHTML = "";

      var results = jsonObject.d.results;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        listsHTML = listsHTML +
            "<p><h1>" + results[i].Title +
            "</h1>" + results[i].Body +
            "</p><hr>";
      }

      document.getElementById("renderList").innerHTML =
          listsHTML;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Function to handle the error event.
    // Prints the error message to the page.
    function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
      document.getElementById("renderList").innerText =
          "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="Root Page" style="text-align:center;">This is the home page</h1>
  <div id="renderList">Placeholder</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in a browser, in the javascript console I get an error: "Uncaught Error: Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url.".

I am under the impression that the problem is in the content of variable `appweburl` that, in all the examples I have found, is provided by SharePoint as part of the query part in the URL. But this implies that a provider-hosted app has been deployed in SharePoint - something I cannot do - and that this app is calling its remotely hosted counterpart.

So the question is: Is it possible to use SharePoint cross-domain library in a page totally external to SharePoint, and if yes, how should I set `hostweburl`, `appweburl` and maybe other things to have access to SharePoint lists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried querying the REST api directly? That would bypass the whole app issue. You would be able to get information through http://SVR/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your_list_name') for example. Some further examples: [Link](http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll read it in depth.
Concerning the REST API, I have considered it and made some experiments. I successfully accessed the list content but only writing the URL in the browser address bar, while I got a 401-UNAUTHORIZED doing the same thing from JavaScript using XmlHttpRRequest. I think that in the first case the browser provides user authentication and there is no Same Origin Policy problem (a whole new page is loaded), while in the second case I must cope with both an authentication problem and a Same Origin Policy problem, that's why I tried SP Cross-Domain Library

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use SharePoint cross-domain library in a page totally external to SharePoint

No, the Cross-domain library for apps for SharePoint is part of SharePoint, it is not available outside of SharePoint.

Here is an example of someone else who had the same requirements.

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/accessing-office-365-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-from-a-local-html-javascript-host/

For reference, I have pasted their code here:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">
    var tokenReq = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    tokenReq += '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
    tokenReq += '  <soap:Body>';
    tokenReq += '    <GetUpdatedFormDigestInformation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />';
    tokenReq += '  </soap:Body>';
    tokenReq += '</soap:Envelope>';
    // you should set these values according your actual request
    var usr = 'username@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com';
    var pwd = 'password';
    var siteFullUrl = "https://yourdomain-my.sharepoint.com";
    var loginUrl = siteFullUrl + "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0";
    var authReq = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
    authReq += '  <s:Header>';
    authReq += '    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>';
    authReq += '    <a:ReplyTo>';
    authReq += '      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>';
    authReq += '    </a:ReplyTo>';
    authReq += '    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>';
    authReq += '    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">';
    authReq += '      <o:UsernameToken>';
    authReq += '        <o:Username>' + usr + '</o:Username>';
    authReq += '        <o:Password>' + pwd + '</o:Password>';
    authReq += '      </o:UsernameToken>';
    authReq += '    </o:Security>';
    authReq += '  </s:Header>';
    authReq += '  <s:Body>';
    authReq += '    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">';
    authReq += '      <a:EndpointReference>';
    authReq += '        <a:Address>' + loginUrl + '</a:Address>';
    authReq += '      </a:EndpointReference>';
    authReq += '      </wsp:AppliesTo>';
    authReq += '      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>';
    authReq += '      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>';
    authReq += '      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>';
    authReq += '    </t:RequestSecurityToken>';
    authReq += '  </s:Body>';
    authReq += '</s:Envelope>';

    function startScript() {
        getToken();
    }
    var token;
    // Step 1: we get the token from the STS
    function getToken() {
            $.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: authReq,
                crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
                contentType: 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
                url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
                    // extract the token from the response data
                    // var token = $(result.responseXML).find("wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken").text(); // we should work with responseText, because responseXML is undefined, due to Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
                    token = $(result.responseText).find("wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken").text();
                    getFedAuthCookies();
                },
                error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    reportError(result, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
        // Step 2: "login" using the token provided by STS in step 1

    function getFedAuthCookies() {
        $.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: token,
            crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            url: loginUrl,
            // dataType: 'html', // default is OK: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
            success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
                // we should update the digest
                //refreshDigestViaWS(); // or alternatively:
                refreshDigestViaREST();
            },
            error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                reportError(result, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    var digest;
    // Step 3a: get the digest from the Sites web service and refresh the one stored locally
    function refreshDigestViaWS() {
            $.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: tokenReq,
                crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
                contentType: 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
                url: siteFullUrl + '/_vti_bin/sites.asmx',
                headers: {
                    'SOAPAction': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetUpdatedFormDigestInformation',
                    'X-RequestForceAuthentication': 'true'
                },
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
                    digest = $(result.responseXML).find("DigestValue").text();
                    sendRESTReq();
                },
                error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                    if ((response.error != undefined) && (response.error.message != undefined)) {
                        alert(response.error.message.value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        // Step 3b: get the digest from the contextinfo and refresh the one stored locally

    function refreshDigestViaREST() {
            $.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: tokenReq,
                crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
                contentType: 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
                url: siteFullUrl + '/_api/contextinfo',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
                    digest = $(result.responseText).find("d\\:FormDigestValue").text();
                    sendRESTReq();
                },
                error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                    if ((response.error != undefined) && (response.error.message != undefined)) {
                        alert(response.error.message.value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        // Step 4: send the REST request

    function sendRESTReq() {
        $.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                __metadata: {
                    type: 'SP.List'
                },
                Title: 'RESTDocLib',
                BaseTemplate: 101
            }),
            // equivalent:       
            // data: "{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Title': 'RESTDocLib','BaseTemplate': 101}" ,
            url: siteFullUrl + "/_api/web/lists",
            crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
            contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            headers: {
                'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
                alert("Created");
            },
            error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                if ((response.error != undefined) && (response.error.message != undefined)) {
                    alert(response.error.message.value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function reportError(result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
        if ((response.error != undefined) && (response.error.message != undefined)) {
            alert(response.error.message.value);
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(startScript);
</script>
```

Comment: i'm getting the following issue in console :-

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51901' is therefore not allowed access.